# How to Use two ViewModels code in XAML using tabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol

I am new to WPF please help me any one.i have two viewmodels 1.ItemCategoryViewModel and 2.TypeViewmodel these two view models come different two tables

```
<tabcontrol>
    <TabItem x:Name="itemtype" Header="ItemType" IsSelected="True" MinHeight="10"> 
        <Grid/>
    </tabitem> 
    <TabItem Header="ItemCategory"  Margin="-1,0" MinHeight="10">
        <grid/>
    </tabitem>
</tabcontrol>
```

In xaml.cs code i want to use both viewmodels.

```
TypeViewmodel povm = new TypeViewmodel();

ItemCategoryViewModel tcvm=new ItemCategoryViewModel();

public PurchaseOrderEntry()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = povm;
    this.DataContext = tcvm;
    txtPONumber.Focus();

    if (povm.FocusMoveTo == null)
        povm.FocusMoveTo = new Action(() => this.FieldNumberToChange());

    if (povm.FocusMoveByTabId == null)
        povm.FocusMoveByTabId = new Action(() =>this.GoToFocusByTabId());

    if (povm.OpenDialogue == null)
        povm.OpenDialogue = new Action<string>(this.OpenDialogue);

    if (tcvm.FocusMoveTo == null)
        tcvm.FocusMoveTo = new Action(() => this.FieldNumberToChange());

    if (tcvm.FocusMoveByTabId == null)
        tcvm.FocusMoveByTabId = new Action(() =>this.GoToFocusByTabId());

    if (tcvm.OpenDialogue == null)
        tcvm.OpenDialogue = new Action<string>(this.OpenDialogue);
}
```

when i am executing only one tab item executed another is not working.viewmodel is overriding. how Can i resolve please help me

Answer (score 1):

replace this code

```
  this.DataContext = povm;
    this.DataContext = tcvm;
```

with this code

```
 this.itemtype.DataContext = povm;
 this.ItemCategory.DataContext = tcvm;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping your two viewmodels in a "MainViewModel" and adjust your bindings in xaml code?

As far as I know you may use different viewmodels in one view for different controls, but I wouldn't change the complete viewmodel for a tabcontrol depending on the tab selected:

Edit:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
    public MainViewModel MainViewModel { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        MainViewModel = new MainViewModel(new TypeViewmodel(), new ItemCategoryViewModel());
        this.DataContext = MainViewModel;
        InitializeComponent();

    }
}
public class MainViewModel
{
    public TypeViewmodel TypeViewmodel { get; set; }
    public ItemCategoryViewModel ItemCategoryViewmodel { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel(TypeViewmodel povm, ItemCategoryViewModel tcvm)
    {
        this.TypeViewmodel = povm;
        this.ItemCategoryViewmodel = tcvm;
    }
}

public class ItemCategoryViewModel
{
    public ItemCategoryViewModel()
    {
        TextBoxMessageItemCategoryViewModel = "Test - ItemCategoryViewModel";
    }
    public String TextBoxMessageItemCategoryViewModel { get; set; }
}

public class TypeViewmodel
{
    public TypeViewmodel()
    {
        TextBoxMessageTypeViewmodel = "Test - TypeViewmodel";
    }
    public String TextBoxMessageTypeViewmodel { get; set; }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem  x:Name="itemtype" Header="ItemType" IsSelected="True" MinHeight="10">
            <Grid DataContext="{Binding TypeViewmodel}">
                <Label Content="{Binding TextBoxMessageTypeViewmodel}"></Label>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="ItemCategory"  Margin="-1,0" MinHeight="10" >
            <Grid DataContext="{Binding ItemCategoryViewmodel}">
                <Label Content="{Binding TextBoxMessageItemCategoryViewModel}"></Label>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Explanation:
I created two realy small viewmodels, so you understand what is beeing bind.
Both inner viewmodels got a string property which will be binded in your tab.
You can replace this with whatever stuff you want to bind.

In Xaml you can see that each Grid in the TabControl binds to a property of the MainViewModel, which is already DataContext of the whole View (in my case Window) then. (You could bind in the TabControl itself aswell)

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding TypeViewmodel}">
```

So at this Point you DataContext is the TypeViewmodel (for all element inside of the grid!), so you can bind the lable content to the property of the TypeViewModel class:

```
 <Label Content="{Binding TextBoxMessageTypeViewmodel}"></Label>
```

Well this is realy basic binding - you should find this in any tutorial aswell...

Hope this helps you.

Comment: thank you so much but how i write in xmal and xaml.cs, Is there any changes in xaml

Comment: I'll edit my answer for you so it becomes a bit clearer, ok?

Comment: Did this help you out, or do you need more detailed help?

Comment: You're welcome.If it solves your problem you might mark it as answer, so other users coming by will have it easier :)